# Solving Integral $\int_{0}^{x}K_{0}\left(\frac{2t^{\beta /2}}{\sigma ^{\beta }}\right)\;dt$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, special-functions, bessel-functions

This question is a continuation of the question posted [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1182353/evaluate-integral-with-eut-gamma-u2). The problem here is to solve the integral with modified Bessel function of second kind, $K_0\left(u\right)$:

$$F\left ( x \right )=\frac{2\beta }{\left ( \sigma \Gamma \left [ \frac{1}{\beta } \right ] \right )^{2}}\int_{0}^{x}K_{0}\left ( \frac{2t^{\frac{\beta }{2}}}{\sigma ^{\beta }} \right )dt$$

where $\beta, \sigma, x>0$ and $F(x)$ is the Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) of a distribution

The main problem here is to solve

$$\int_{0}^{x}K_{0}\left ( \frac{2t^{\frac{\beta }{2}}}{\sigma ^{\beta }} \right )dt$$

I tried using guidance from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/441374/integrating-modified-bessel-function-of-the-second-kind) but no luck. How can this be solved? Thanks

**Answer:**

Follow @Lucian's comment below

Comment: Are you looking for an analytical methodology?  Or are you seeking a numerical approximation?

Comment: @Dr.MV: Analytical solution to the problem. For numerical approximation, I can simulate using Monte Carlo in MATLAB

Comment: After an appropriate substitution, use [this result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/74XND.png).

Comment: @Lucian: very helpful! thanks!